# windows 7 not booting boot-repair problem

Tags: boot-repair

When I run Boot-repair I get this message:

> Please use this software in a live-session (live-CD or live-USB). This
>   will enable this feature.

What do I have to do?

Comment: Get boot-repaid from http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/ , get Unetbootin (for linux) from: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ . Read this http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/03/how-to-create-bootable-linux-usb-drive.html to know how to use Unetbootin

Comment: What has this got to do with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

1. [Boot on an Ubuntu disc (USB or DVD).](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD)
2. Choose 'Try Ubuntu'.
3. Connect internet
4. [Install and run Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu)

Alternatively, you can:

1. Download a [Boot-Repair-Disk](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home) image
2. Burn it on a CD or an USB key
3. [Boot on it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD). This will launch the [Boot-Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) automatically.